# Azure Synapse Copy Data from BigQuery, Source ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][BigQuery] (131) Unable to authenticate with Google BigQuery Storage API

Tags: google-bigquery, google-api, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am getting this error at the Source tab at the Use query (Table, Query) Query, when doing a copy data activity at the Azure Synapse pipeline.

Unable to authenticate with Google BigQuery Storage API:

[image: Unable to authenticate with Google BigQuery Storage API]
.

The strange thing is I can preview data at the Source dataset, I can also preview data when select the Use query Table option.

[image: can preview table]

I can even run query to select the table's schema

[image: can query schema]

```
SELECT
*
FROM
`3082`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
```

but I get this authentication error when selecting columns

```
SELECT
*
FROM
`3082.gcp_billing_export_v1_019F74_6EA5E8_C96548`;
```

Comment: Refer this [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/google-bigquery#unable-to-authenticate-with-google-bigquery-storage-api) and check if all the required permissions are there.

Comment: @Aswin, thank you for answering this question. I was missing the BigQuery user role. Please post the above comment again as answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][BigQuery] (131) Unable to authenticate with Google BigQuery Storage API. Check your account permissions

The above error is due to issue in authentication of BigQuery Storage API. The permission required to access data from BigQuery are,

- bigquery.readsessions.create
- bigquery.readsessions.getData
- bigquery.readsessions.update

The role ***BigQuery User*** will help in giving above permissions.

**Reference:**

1. **Google cloud doc** on  [Access Control - BigQuery User](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bigquery.user).
2. **MS doc** on [Google BigQuery connector issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/google-bigquery#unable-to-authenticate-with-google-bigquery-storage-api)